# Image reflected when exported to png file

Tags: image-processing

I produced an image that combines a couple of objects by using the following command

```
Fig = Show[a1, a2, ar1, ar2, springnew, PlotRange -> All, 
BoxRatios -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {1.23, -1.90, -2.5}, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 300}]
```

Here is how image looks like,

[image: Original figure]

But when I export it as a png file,

```
Export["Fig.png", Fig, ImageResolution -> 500]
```

This is how the save file looks like,

[image: saved figure]

The two images seem flipped upside down, at least from different views. But I did specify the viewpoint when I produce the image. I'm sure it's not due to the ImageResolution option in the export command. The save image looks the same even I turned off the option.

Comment: Could you include the complete minimal code that is needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It could be that you have changed the orientation by hand at some point. When re-rendering, Mathematica remembers some things like that, so it may not show the image that the code generates. You can delete the image and re-render it without any previous output to see what the code actually says it looks like, if this is the problem.

Comment: might try the `Export` option `"ImageTopOrientation" ->Bottom` or `"ImageTopOrientation" ->Top`.

Comment: @kglr I tried both, but neither worked. But for Top, it seems the view is from the back.

Comment: @C.E. I deleted the image and rerun the code, but still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @C.E. I restart mathematica and it is indeed as you said, mathematica may not show the image specified by the code.

Comment: Instead of "delete the image" I should have said "delete the cell containing the image", this should be sufficient. I'm glad the problem got solved.